# How do I create an executable jar file from my program so I can run it per double-click or from command line?

Tags: java, exception, jar

I am using the program Eclipse to compile my .jar

http://pastebin.com/AY79DbgY

It should only be a console window. I am just starting out on java, so I have no idea what I did wrong.

When I try to run the .jar I compiled in Eclipse, it doesn't run at all, but if I open cmd, and try to run it via there, it prints out this, none of which I understand at all:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: server.  Program will exit.
```

I just wanted to make a .jar that I could run from any computer without having to use Eclipse. It runs just fine in the console there.

Also, every once in a while, when I terminate the script in the console in Eclipse, I get this error, but otherwise it seems to run just fine:

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
            at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
            at finalproject.main(finalproject.java:432)
```

So I kinda have no idea what I'm doing at this point.

If my typing seems like I'm young, it's true, I'm only 15.

Comment: Is your class path set up correctly?

Comment: What command are you using to start it from the command prompt?  Are you specifying the package name of the class that has the main() method?  i.e com.foo.Server

Comment: Did you check the `/bin` directory of your Eclipse project folder?  If your project is running in Eclipse fine then Eclipse has already compiled it, and has likely already created a `.jar` in the `/bin` folder.

Comment: Google is your friend. You've got classpath problems.

Comment: For fun I would submit your code to "Codereview" after you release it, they would have some fun with it (Not that it looks poorly structured, but it could use a lot of refactoring and you might learn a lot from how it can be refactored)

Comment: why is it looking for class "server" and not "finalproject"? that should be a clue as to what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the name of the class that contains the main() method that's executed when you run the JAR in the manifest.  Take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for instructions.

Comment: Honestly, I just wanted to double-click on the .jar and have it open a console window with my program, using cmd was just my second guess at trying to make it work. I got it to run in cmd already by using "java -cp file.jar finalproject".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really did here, so here are some guesses from my glass ball:

- You are calling your program by `java -cp file.jar server`, while it would have to be `java -cp file.jar finalproject`.

  Use the latter command.
- Your IDE indicates some main class (`server`) in the Jar Manifest which does not exist, and you are using `java -jar file.jar`. This would also explain why you can't run it from Eclipse.

  Check your build settings to indicate the right main class.

Comment: It does run in Eclipse before I compile it into a jar. The problem is after I compile it. I go to the directory of the jar in cmd, then I typed in "run finalproject.jar" and I get the above erors. 

Your first suggestion did work, but honestly what I really wanted to do was just double-click on the .jar file to open a console window with my program. Running it in cmd was my second guess at trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In your JAR file you should have a file called MANIFEST.MF (under folder META-INF)
This describes various properties of your jar file.

You should edit it and add:

```
Main-Class: finalproject
```

I would put your class in a package because having it in the default package invites a little classpath trouble.

You can open the JAR file using winzip or winrar and edit the MANIFEST.MF directly just to test, but in reality you should have it outside together with the classes you are packaging in the JAR so that each time you generate the JAR file you include it with the rest of the classes.

Here is how you include the file with additions to the default manifest when generating the JAR file. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: finalproject

That is what is in the manifest.mf already, along with 2 blank lines under that.

Comment: and what is the full java command you are using to run the program? From your stack trace it seems like its looking for a class named 'server'

Comment: I was just typing "run finalproject.jar" into the cmd once I got into the correct directory.

Comment: run? That is definitely not the actual command. The actual command must start with 'java'. Do you have a batch file in there named run.bat maybe? You have to open it and see what its doing in there.